# Multiple shortcodes on a same page not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, I am trying to display ratings (using kk star rating plugin) for different past bookings in my plugin. I am using `do_shortcode()` for different bookings with different ids. This is being echoed in a partial file.

```php
<?php 
/* GIVE RATINGS IF NOT ALREADY GIVEN */
if ($ratings_possible) {
      echo do_shortcode("[kkstarratings id=" . $booking->id . "]");
?>
```

Here `$booking->id` is giving a unique booking id number based on which I am trying to get unique rating for each booking.

### Issue

Currently, main file runs loop three times and this snippet does display stars perfectly, but of those three star-bar, last one is actually working. Last one accepts the ratings and updates the average, but the first two are not working. We can hover over all there stars-bar and click, but the only last one of it is actually working.

I have also used `kk_star_ratings()` method but same result.

### More details

The following is a part of `dashboard.php` code. It is displaying every appointment/booking of a customer. Here `$customer->future_bookings` is displaying upcoming bookings (where obviously `$ratings_possible` is set to false). However, on `$customer->past_bookings` I have set `$ratings_possible` to true. Followed by the partial file that is responsible for each booking detail i.e. `include('_booking_tile.php');`

**dashboard.php**

```php
<div class="customer-bookings-tiles">
                    <?php 
                    foreach($customer->future_bookings as $booking){
                        $editable_booking = true;
                        $ratings_possible = false;
                        include('_booking_tile.php');
                    } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                if($customer->past_bookings){ ?>
                <div class="latepoint-section-heading-w">
                    <h5 class="latepoint-section-heading"><?php _e('Past '.$appointterm, 'latepoint'); ?></h5>
                    <div class="heading-extra"><?php printf( __('%d '.$appointterm, 'latepoint'), count($customer->past_bookings)); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-bookings-tiles">
                    <?php 
                        foreach($customer->past_bookings as $booking){
                            $editable_booking = false;
                            $ratings_possible = true;
                            include('_booking_tile.php');
                    } ?>
                </div>
```

Now, on the `_booking_tile.php`, it contains details of each booking like agent, time, status etc. Through `$booking` object we are getting the variables of a particular booking and their values and everything. Here is some part of code:

**_booking_tile.php**

```php
<div class="customer-booking-info-row">
            <span class="booking-info-label"><?php _e($agentterm, 'latepoint'); ?></span>
            <span class="booking-info-value"><?php echo $booking->agent->full_name; ?></span></div>
        <div class="customer-booking-info-row">
            <span class="booking-info-label"><?php _e('Status', 'latepoint'); ?></span>
            <span class="booking-info-value status-<?php echo $booking->status; ?>"><?php echo $booking->nice_status; ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($editable_booking) { ?>
        <div class="customer-booking-buttons">
            <a href="<?php echo $booking->ical_download_link; ?>" target="_blank" class="latepoint-btn latepoint-btn-primary latepoint-btn-link">
                <i class="latepoint-icon latepoint-icon-ui-83"></i>
                <span><?php _e('Add to Calendar', 'latepoint'); ?></span>
            </a>
            <?php /* <a href="#" class="latepoint-btn"><i class="latepoint-icon latepoint-icon-ui-46"></i><span><?php _e('Edit', 'latepoint'); ?></span></a> */ ?>
            <a href="#" class="latepoint-btn latepoint-btn-danger latepoint-request-booking-cancellation latepoint-btn-link" data-route="<?php echo OsRouterHelper::build_route_name('bookings', 'request_cancellation'); ?>">
                <i class="latepoint-icon latepoint-icon-ui-24"></i>
                <span><?php _e('Cancel', 'latepoint'); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php /* GIVE RATINGS IF NOT ALREADY GIVEN */
    if ($ratings_possible) {
                     echo do_shortcode("[kkstarratings id=" . $booking->id . "]");
    ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Resulting HTML code is perfectly fine, every rating-star (kk star plugin) has perfect code it has unique IDs meaning it should work fine. Moreover, as I said before when I insert three shortcodes with different IDs, it works fine.

That stars are displaying perfectly, but only the third one is actually working. When I click third one it records my rating and displays the average. While first two are not.

- Stars work when I insert their shortcodes manually through WordPress. So it means that multiple shortcodes with IDs is possible.
- Author provides `kk_star_rating()` function that can be used in the code, but it gives same result.
- Only the last star is working others are just not recording anything. All three have same resulting HTML code except for the IDs which will be unique.

I will be happy to answer more of your questions.

Here's the screenshot, Third one is giving me the result when I click. But I can only hover over the first two and click multiple times with no result.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FPvQ.png)

Comment: (It sounds a lot like this might actually be a client-side problem though, likely one of the “usual suspects” such as duplicated IDs messing things up. Have you checked the plugin documentation if it has anything to say about whether it can be used multiple times on the same page …?)

Comment: I am sorry for that but I felt that it could be a simple php or wordpress problem that I couldn't see. I have checked that IDs are different. And yes, plugin does support multiple ratings on single page by this short code. Interestingly, if I insert shortcodes myself on a page with different IDs, all three are working.

Comment: Have you verified that `$booking->id` in your code has the correct, expected value then in each case? Have you compared the resulting HTML between your two versions?

Comment: I think your issue lays in the loop? Maybe? Is there more code you can display? 
Everyone is trying to understand your problem. Your question is being voted on to be closed, but if you give some more information, we might be able to help you. Also, "if($ratings_possible)" it might be better if you do If(!empty$ratings_possible) instead or explicitly look for false.

Comment: I have added more details. `$booking->id` gives different output for each booking. For `$ratings_possible`, I have added bit more code, but I don't think it is an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some sort of problem with the plugin. It was not compatible with newest version of WordPress. Used a different plugin and it worked fine. Calling multiple shortcodes through a loop worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.